# How to make Apache2 stop refusing to serve Flask on port 8080 (while it serves it on port 80 ?)

Tags: flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to make a "Hello world" application made with Python and Flask. I want it to be deployed with Apache2 on port 8080.

Up to now, my Apache2 server listens on port 80 for http and on port 443 for https. It don't have anything on 80 so I first tried to use it for my Flask app.

Following Flask documentation, I installed the wsgi module on Apache2 and I created my Flask configuration in Apache2 with a VirtualHost attached to port 80. I restarted Apache2 and all was fine : I saw "Hello world" on my browser. And I was happy.

Then, I decided just to move from port 80 to port 8080. I add a Listen directive in ports.conf on Apache, I changed the VirtualHost *:80 to VirtualHost *:8080 in my configuration. And I restarted Apache2. And since then, it doesn't work at all !

I have absolutely no error messages in /var/log/apache2/error.log nor anywhere else.

I double (or infinite-) checked that in Apache2 ports.conf listens to 8080.
I checked that in Apache2 my VirtualHost is on 8080 too. 
I checked that 8080 is listening when Apache2 is restarted...

I cannot figure what is not working. Why does this work on port 80 and not on port 8080... ? I also have a 443 SSL port with a VirtualHost for a another application on the same server and ServerName. It is possible that with port 8080, there is a conflict (I must say I am not an expert of Apache2).

Here are informations on my configuration and codes :

Apache2 ports.conf :

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
   Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
   Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Apache2 conf for my virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName aaa.bbb.fr
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/flaskapps/helloworldapp/
        LogLevel trace5
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        WSGIDaemonProcess helloworldapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskapps/helloworldapp/helloworldapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/flaskapps/helloworldapp>
                WSGIProcessGroup helloworldapp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Helloworldapp.py :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def helloworldapp():
    return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

(The port=8080 seems to have no effect : it doesn't prevent my code to run on port 80)

Helloworldapp.wsgi :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/flaskapps/helloworldapp')
from helloworldapp import app as application
```

Results of netstat -lntp :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Comment: what happens if you run your flask in anther port different from 8080 maybe the port is already used by flask

Comment: As I said, on port 80, everything is fine. I tried on 88, 5000, whatever... still the same result (that is : nothing :( )
And if I change app.run(port=8080, debug=True) to app.run(), it doesn't change anything too.

Comment: same issue did you resolve this?

Comment: No. And finally I moved on to another subject. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar situation: [Expose a different port for Flask App inside Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690485/expose-a-different-port-for-flask-app-inside-docker-container)

It looks like flask does not really deal with ports. If you use Docker you can expose a different port this way. This is not a great solution for your problem but maybe it gives an idea. I gave up on changing port of flask and simply do it using docker.